# Iterator to one past the last element in list

Tags: c++

I'm working on implementing my own list. I see that std::list::end() returns iterator to one past the last element in the list container. I'm wondering how the position of this past-the-end element is estimated due to list elements are stored in non-contiguous memory locations.

```
std::list<int> ls;
ls.push_back(1);
ls.push_back(2);
std::list<int>::iterator it = ls.end();
std::cout << &(*it) << std::endl << &(*++it) << std::endl << &(*++it) << std::endl;
```

As the code above presents, I can even increment the iterator to point to the next elements. How can it be known at which positions (in memory) the next elements will be stored?

Comment: You don't. For a list iterator, the end iterator ***always*** points to one past the end of the list. Add more values to the end of the list, the same exact iterator ***still points to one past the end of the list***. The "one past the end of the list" iterator, for `std::list` forever points to one past the end of the list, and will continue to do so forever, whether the list is empty, or eats up all your ram.

Comment: This is not my question. The question is how the list know on which position in the memory will the next element be stored before it will be added to the list?

Comment: I answered it. It doesn't. If you use the end iterator to add a new value to the list, it will go to whatever memory gets allocated to it. And the list iterator will still point to "one past" the end of the list. Hint: "one past the end of the list" does not, I repeat, ***does not*** mean a specific memory location. It is a "conceptual value". Some magic and mysterious value that's always interpreted, by list methods, as meaning one after the last value in the list.

Comment: The code only presents that gods of Undefined Behaviour are mocking you. Dereferencing or incrementing `end()` iterator is UB and your program is invalid.

Comment: OK. Any thoughts then how can I implement the end() method to my custom list? Will pointer/iterator to the last element of the list + 1 (next position in the memory) would be ok?

Comment: Regarding your own implementation, I can see two possibilities (there are probably more): you can have `end()` to be `nullptr`, then by following `next` pointers you eventually get to `nullptr` and you know it's stop. Or you could have a sentinel object that means "end" and you can recognize it (maybe it can have `next` pointing to `this` or maybe you can just store pointer to the sentinel in your list object or iterators themselves).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can it be known at which positions (in memory) the next elements will be stored?

It is not. Also, using that memory address as (part of) the past-the-end iterator would be incorrect.

**Is not:**
An iterator is not (necessarily) a pointer. An iterator is not required to store a memory address. What is required is that the de-reference operator be able to calculate a memory address (returned in the form of a reference). *Good news, everyone!* Applying the de-reference operator to the past-the-end iterator is undefined behavior. So even this reduced requirement is not applicable to the past-the-end iterator. If you are storing an address, go ahead and store whatever you want. (Just be consistent since two past-the-end iterators must compare equal.)

If your iterator does store a pointer (which admittedly is probably common), a simple approach would be to store whatever you would put in the `next` field of the last node in the list. This is typically either `nullptr` or a pointer to the list's sentinel node.

**Would be incorrect:**
A `std::list` does not invalidate iterators when elements are added to the list. *This includes the past-the-end iterator.* (See [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container#Iterator_invalidation).) If your past-the-end iterator pointed to where the next element would be stored, it would be invalidated by adding that element to the list. Thus, you would fail to meet the iterator invalidation requirements for a `std::list`. So not only is storing that address in the past-the-end iterator impossible, it's not allowed.